# How to use before_action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have some methods in my controller.
First of all I write

```
before_action :require_user
before_action :require_rights, only: [:show, :my_method]
```

Can I put methods dynamically ? e.g.

```
before_action :require_rights, only: current_user.allowed_actions
```

I think to save method names somewhere and configure each user to groups with access rights. Or there are better solutions in existing gems ?

Comment: Did you try it? Was there an error?

Comment: Yes I did. But there are problem with acess to methods, even I describe one row before_action :require_user, only: [:show] I still have acess to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#controller
before_action :require_rights

def require_rights
  unless current_user.allowed_actions
    raise 'not authorized'
  end
end
```

Make your condition in your method can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in such a way.

```
before_action :require_user
before_action :require_rights


def require_rights
  fail 'Not allowed' unless current_user.allowed_actions.include?(action_name) # Guard to check if user allowed to do certain action
end
```

Also I would recommend you to create a special class which will handle this logic for you. Example:

```
class RightsPolicyService
  attr_reader :user

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def allowed?(controller_name, action_name)
    # Define here your custom logic for checking if user is allowed
    user.allowed_controllers.include?(controller_name) &&
      user.allowed_actions.include?(action_name)
  end
end

# And in the controller
def require_rights
  fail 'Not allowed' unless RightsPolicyService.new(current_user).allowed?(controller_name, action_name)
end
```

**Note:** failing is just made an example, you should generate a response in this case or redirect somewhere.